# ERROR npm failed with exit code 2 Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/vsce package --no-yarn

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, yarnpkg, vscode-extensions

this is the exact error shown in cmd

```
  TS1323: Dynamic imports are only supported when the '--module' flag is set to 'es2020', 'esnext', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', or 'umd'.
```

**ERROR  npm failed with exit code 2**
**Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/vsce package --no-yarn**

````
 at Object.execSync (child_process.js:652:15)
 at CodeUtil.packageExtension (/home/.../out/util/codeUtil.js:180:23)
 at ExTester.<anonymous> (/home/.../out/extester.js:77:27)
 at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
 at /home/.../out/extester.js:18:71
 at new Promise (<anonymous>)
 at __awaiter (/home/.../out/extester.js:14:12)
 at ExTester.installVsix (/home/.../out/extester.js:58:16)
 at ExTester.<anonymous> (/home/.../out/extester.js:112:24)```

'module' flag is already set to 'commonjs' and 'target' is set to 'es6'
````

Answer (score 0):

solved now.
needed to add "test-resources" in tsconfig.json > "exclude"